# Concrete5 advanced Grid

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

My customer wants to maintain their own grid so that they can fully design their design like they want. Problem in this is when i add a `Bootstrap` grid in `concrete5` that it defaults created a col-md-6 for example.

Problem is that i have a design with 2 options, mobile or desktop. In my setup on default i have it like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><img></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><img></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
</div>
```

The problem over here is that this should be the layout for the "desktop" version instead so i'd need to use the col-lg instead. Fo all smaller devices (col-md and below) the rows should be fullscreen so it should look like:
    
      A
      
    
    
      
      B

How can i achieve that in concrete5? The other problem i have is that if i make this responsive the design would show it in this order for mobile:

- Text
- Photo
- Photo
- Text

Where the customer wants it like     where the col-push would come in.

How can i do that if even possible with Concrete5? I ofcourse can set it all manually and make the inside block as content but by doing that it is not flexible at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the theme area layout presets (which are defined in the page_theme.php).
The downside is you'll have to define all possibilities.

Example:

```
public function getThemeAreaLayoutPresets(){
$presets = array(
    array(
        'handle' => '2_columns_no_push',
        'name' => '2 Columns no push',
        'container' => '<div class="row"></div>',
        'columns' => array(
            '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>',
            '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"></div>'
        )
    )
);
return $presets;
}
```

Developers documentation : http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/designing-for-concrete5/adding-complex-custom-layout-presets-in-your-theme